# Turn off errorbars in seaborn plots

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot, line-plot, pointplot

```py
import seaborn as sns

# sample data
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='class', y='age', hue='survived')
```

[image]

Is there a way to turn off the black error bars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **The `errorbar` parameter should be used instead.**
- The `ci` parameter is deprecated from **seaborn 0.12.0**, as per [v0.12.0 (September 2022): More flexible errorbars](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.12.0.html#more-flexible-errorbars). This applies to the following plots:

  - [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html), and [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with `kind='bar'`
  - [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html), and [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) with `kind='line'`

    - `g = sns.relplot(data=df, kind='line', x='class', y='age', hue='survived', col='sex', errorbar=None)`
    - `ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x='class', y='age', hue='survived', errorbar=None)`
  - [`seaborn.pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html), and [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with `kind='point'`

    - `g = sns.catplot(data=df, kind='point', x='class', y='age', hue='survived', col='sex', errorbar=None)`
    - `ax = sns.pointplot(data=df, x='class', y='age', hue='survived', errorbar=None)`

```py
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='class', y='age', hue='survived', errorbar=None)
```

[image]

```py
g = sns.catplot(data=df, kind='bar', x='class', y='age', hue='survived', col='sex', errorbar=None)
```

[image]

Answer (score 72):

Have you tried the `ci` argument? According to [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html#seaborn.barplot):

> ci : float or None, optional
>       Size of confidence intervals to draw around estimated values. If
>       `None`, no bootstrapping will be performed, and error bars will
>       not be drawn.

```
sns.barplot(x=df['Time'], y=df['Volume_Count'], ax=ax7, ci=None)
```

Comment: For others coming to this answer, `ci` is now depreciated (as of seaborne version 0.12.0). You should now use `errorbar` as suggested by derekchased

Answer (score 12):

Complete example for @Diziet Asahi

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

# Usual case
sns.barplot(x='class', y='age', hue='survived', data=df)

# No error bars (ci=None)
sns.barplot(x='class', y='age', hue='survived', data=df, ci=None)
```

## Output for Usual case

[image]

## Output No error bars

[image]