# Seaborn pairplot displaying mean line

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm using a seaborn pointplot and for some reason seaborn is displaying the mean value of my x variable as a straight line. I'd like to remove this line if possible, tried looking at the docs but still cannot figure it out. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: what does your data look like?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html): `A point plot represents an estimate of central tendency for a numeric variable by the position of scatter plot points and provides some indication of the uncertainty around that estimate using error bars`. Also: `a point plot shows only the mean (or other estimator) value`. This function is meant to be used to show central tendencies. The mean is a measurement of central tendency, this is why it's showing. Try some other functions instead, or pass something non-default to the `estimator=` parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off error bars in Seaborn Bar Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088585/turn-off-error-bars-in-seaborn-bar-plot)