# Dark bars don't match legend in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

Something went wrong with the bar plot. I didn't get an error message, but for some reason my plot has dark bars that don't match any color in the legend. Also the highest bar value should be 36 not 13!
Any idea about what could have caused this?

Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (25,15))
ax = sns.barplot(data=data, x=col_name1, y=col_name2, hue=col_name3, saturation=1)
```

[image]

Comment: You need to post your data for the code to be reproducible

Comment: [Turn off errorbars in seaborn plots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40088585/7758804)

Comment: [Why doesn't the seaborn plot show a confidence interval / error bars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59127738/7758804)

Answer (score 0):

This issue persists when I make a bar plot with a hue space so large like this.

I solved this issue for this plot by using a stacked bar plot instead of a bar plot.

Here's the code:

```
filtered_data = df['col_name1'].value_counts().index

data = filtered_data.pivot(index='col_name1', columns='col_name2', values='col_name3').fillna(0)

# Create the horizontal stacked bar plot, for a vertical stacked plot kind=bar without the h. 
ax = data.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(25, 15))
plt.show()
```